# Only 2 out of 9 PHP form fields being sent to email

Tags: php, webforms, field

I've got a pretty simple contact form (or so I thought), but only 2 out of 9 contact fields are being delivered to my inbox. Strangely enough, it's the last two fields in the list, although the 'from' email address, and subject matter are working fine.

```
 <form id="quote" class="contact_form" action="contact.php" method="post">
  <h2>Easy Contact Form</h2>
  <h4>Personal</h4>

    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required class="required" >

    <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
     <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" required class="required" >


    <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="jsmith@email.com" class="required email">

    <label>Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />

  <h4>Address</h4>

    <label>House #:</label>
    <input type="text" name="house" id="house" />

    <label>Street:</label>
    <input type="text" name="street" id="street" />

   <label>Town/City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="town" id="town" />

    <label>Postcode:</label>
    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" />

  <h4>Lender</h4>

    <label>Company Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" />

  <input class="btn" type="image" src="images/submit_btn.jpg"/>
</form>
```

And here's the PHP:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = $_REQUEST['email']; 
$EmailTo = "me@email.com";
$Subject = "Information";
$Title = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['title'])); 
$Fullname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fullname'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
$House = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['house'])); 
$Street = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['street'])); 
$Town = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['town'])); 
$Postcode = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['postcode'])); 
$Companyname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['companyname'])); 


// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
echo "Error";
exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "Title: ";
$Body .= $Title;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Fullname: ";
$Body .= $Fullname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Phone: ";
$Body .= $Phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "house: ";
$Body .= $house;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Street: ";
$Body .= $Street;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Town: ";
$Body .= $Town;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Postcode: ";
$Body .= $Postcode;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company Name: ";
$Body .= $Companyname;

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
echo "Succes";
}
else{
echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: How is the Trim function defined?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
// prepare email body text
$Body = "Title: ";
$Body .= $Title;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Fullname: ";
$Body .= $Fullname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Phone: "; //needs dot
$Body .= $Phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "house: ";
$Body .= $house;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Street: "; //needs dot
$Body .= $Street;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Town: "; //needs dot
$Body .= $Town;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Postcode: "; //needs dot
$Body .= $Postcode;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company Name: ";
$Body .= $Companyname;
```

You need to make sure each line has `.=` instead of just `=`. Near the bottom where you have `$Body = "Postcode: ";`, you're resetting the entire $Body variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from `$body`.

```
// prepare email body text
$Body = "Title: ";
$Body .= $Title;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Fullname: ";
$Body .= $Fullname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Phone: ";
$Body .= $Phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "house: ";
$Body .= $house;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Street: ";
$Body .= $Street;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Town: ";
$Body .= $Town;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body = "Postcode: ";
$Body .= $Postcode;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company Name: ";
$Body .= $Companyname;
```

The first variable declaration `$Body = "Title: ";`is fine, however after that you need to make sure you are appending to the string using `.=`.

Each time after the intital declaration you use `=`, it clears everything assigned or appended previously and starts again.

This is why you only see the last 2 form fields, because `$Body = "Postcode: ";` restarts the variable, removing everything before.

Use `.=` for every single line except the first one, which should be an `=`.

Hope this helps!